# Why is smooth scroll suddenly impossible on this WP theme?

Tags: wordpress, scroll, wordpress-theming, smoothing

I use the MouseWheel Smooth Scroll plugin in Wordpress all the time for my sites. It always works. A week ago, I started a new site and noticed that smooth scrolling wasn't working on it. Today I tried fixing it and just can't understand what the problem is. I used the theme Shapely and MouseWheel Smooth Scroll just two weeks ago and that site is working fine: https://xharris.com 
I even installed a new wp site 30 minutes ago to test with demo content.....and it still doesn't work!! Infact, NO smooth scrolling plugin works. I can't figure this out.

Here's what works and what doesn't: 
Smooth with anchors: yes. 
Smooth with back to top: yes. 
General mouse scroll up and down: no.

Where am I going wrong???
You can see it NOT working here https://xharris.com/porto

**i know the 'anchors' and 'to top' work because i tested them on another site really quick with other plugins. unfortunatley....i don't need them. i just need mousewheel scrolling to be smooth..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the browser console on the proto site, you can see that for whatever reason allowedBrowsers is undefined on the SmoothScroll script:

```
SmoothScroll.min.js?ver=1.4.10:formatted:350 Uncaught ReferenceError: allowedBrowsers is not defined
    at SmoothScroll.min.js?ver=1.4.10:formatted:350
    at SmoothScroll.min.js?ver=1.4.10:formatted:351
    at SmoothScroll.min.js?ver=1.4.10:formatted:384
```

You'll need to modify it to add this variable into either the script or add a script that adds this variable before the SmoothScroll script is loaded.

In the current site, this is the value that it currently has:

```js
var allowedBrowsers=["IEWin7","Chrome","Safari"];
```

**Edit:** After looking closer at your website, it seems like it is loading some scripts over HTTP instead of HTTPS and Chrome is blocking these scripts from being loaded for security reasons. This is the reason why SmoothScroll isn't working I believe. Please make sure the following scripts are being loaded by changing the "http" part to "https":

```
http://xharris.com/porto/wp-content/uploads/wpmss/wpmss.min.js?ver=1589445996
http://xharris.com/porto/wp-content/uploads/wpmss/wpmssab.min.js?ver=1589445996
```

Comment: first thing, thanks for the help! now i just spent about 5 minutes reading and rereading your answer. i really wish i studied java. i saw the code in the .min.js file in the plugin editor....but honestly i have no idea how to write java or where to put it within that page....is there anything i could copy & paste from somewhere? sorry i forgot to mention that i'm a not really educated in code...

Comment: Check my edits, if you fix Chrome loading mixed content it should work.